# Is there an easy way to access my gmail account and download a specific excel file attachment from a specific email?

Tags: python, gmail, imap, pop3

I have received an email that has an excel file as an attachment.

I would

I would like to use python to do the following:

- Access my gmail account when I provide my username and password
- Search for the specific email according to the mail's subject
- Download one (or all) attachment from this mail into a folder of my choosing

I have seen some guides but none of them work for me and I wonder if there is a specific known 3rd party lib that does the following.

I have used the following script I found:

```
import email, getpass, imaplib, os

detach_dir = '.'  # directory where to save attachments (default: current)
user = input("Enter your GMail username:")
pwd = getpass.getpass("Enter your password: ")

# connecting to the gmail imap server
m = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL("imap.gmail.com")
m.login(user, pwd)
m.select("cs2043")  # here you a can choose a mail box like INBOX instead
# use m.list() to get all the mailboxes

resp, items = m.search(None,
                   "ALL")  # you could filter using the IMAP rules here 
(check http://www.example-code.com/csharp/imap-search-critera.asp)
items = items[0].split()  # getting the mails id

for emailid in items:
    resp, data = m.fetch(emailid,
                         "(RFC822)")  # fetching the mail, "`(RFC822)`" means 
"get the whole stuff", but you can ask for headers only, etc
    email_body = data[0][1]  # getting the mail content
   mail = email.message_from_string(email_body)  # parsing the mail content 
to get a mail object

    # Check if any attachments at all
    if mail.get_content_maintype() != 'multipart':
        continue

    print
    "[" + mail["From"] + "] :" + mail["Subject"]

    # we use walk to create a generator so we can iterate on the parts and 
forget about the recursive headach
    for part in mail.walk():
        # multipart are just containers, so we skip them
        if part.get_content_maintype() == 'multipart':
            continue

        # is this part an attachment ?
        if part.get('Content-Disposition') is None:
            continue

        # filename = part.get_filename()

        filename = mail["From"] + "_hw1answer"

        att_path = os.path.join(detach_dir, filename)

        # Check if its already there
        if not os.path.isfile(att_path):
            # finally write the stuff
            fp = open(att_path, 'wb')
            fp.write(part.get_payload(decode=True))
            fp.close()
```

The problem with this script is that as soon as I enter my correct password I receive:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gmail_report_analysis.py", line 9, in <module>
    m.login(user, pwd)
  File "C:\Users\Amir\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\imaplib.py", 
line 593, in login
    raise self.error(dat[-1])
imaplib.error: b'[AUTHENTICATIONFAILED] Invalid credentials (Failure)'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the python API for gmail to automate actions on your gmail account.

1. enable gmail api on google developer console and download `credentials.json`
2. install the python library - `pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client oauth2client`
3. create your python code file -

   ```
   from __future__ import print_function
   from googleapiclient.discovery import build
   from httplib2 import Http
   from oauth2client import file, client, tools

   # If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.json.
   SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly'

   def main():
       """Shows basic usage of the Gmail API.
       Lists the user's Gmail labels.
       """
       # The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
       # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
       # time.
       store = file.Storage('token.json')
       creds = store.get()
       if not creds or creds.invalid:
           flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets('credentials.json', SCOPES)
           creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store)
       service = build('gmail', 'v1', http=creds.authorize(Http()))

       # Call the Gmail API
       results = service.users().labels().list(userId='me').execute()
       labels = results.get('labels', [])

       if not labels:
           print('No labels found.')
       else:
           print('Labels:')
           for label in labels:
               print(label['name'])

   if __name__ == '__main__':
       main()
   ```

The above code is just to login to your gmail account and pull the labels in your gmail mailbox. There are other actions also you can perform like search messages and download attachments. Please refer [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/filtering) for more information.